# LINQ GroupBy and Select on different property

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by, linq-to-objects

If I have the following collection:

```
var foos = new List<Foo>
{
    new Foo{ Name = "A", Value = 1 },
    new Foo{ Name = "B", Value = 1 },
    new Foo{ Name = "B", Value = 2 },
    new Foo{ Name = "C", Value = 1 },
};
```

And I want to end-up with:

```
A-1
B-2
C-1
```

Where in the case of the duplicate "B" I want to select the "B" with the highest Value?

Something like:

```
var filteredFoos = foos.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select_Duplicate_With_Highest_Value
```

Comment: lol, three answers that are all the same with different preferred styles. Take your pick!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var query = from p in foos
            group p by p.Name into g
            select new
            {
                Name = g.Key,
                Value = g.Max(a => a.Value)
            };
```

Comment: this works, if for no other reason I'm marking this as the answer because you need more points/medals than Justin! though the other answers work equally well

Comment: @ErOx Aye, they do. As mentioned in the comment above they should all give the exact same result, just a different way of writing it. I just personally prefer the query syntax over method syntax.

Answer (score 5):

```
var filteredFoos = 
    foos.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
        .Select(x => new { Name = x.Key, Value = x.Max(f => f.Value) });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
var filteredFoos = foos.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                       .Select(p => new { p.Key, p.Max(x => x.Value) });
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with more than 2 columns:

```
var subquery = from p in foos
            group p by p.Name into g
            select new
            {
                Name = g.Key,
                Value = g.Max(a => a.Value)
            };
var query = from f in foos
            join s in subquery 
              on f.Name equals s.Name
            where f.Value == s.Value
            select f;
```

If this is against SQL, make sure Name is a primitive.